# PostGIS generate center POINTS from multilinestrings and multipolygons (for each line and polygon) in the memory

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, multi-polygon

Let's assume, I have a mixed geometry type table in PostgreSQL  The multipart geometries don't intersect themselves. I would like to generate a center point collection from every geometry. I know how to create centroids from singlepart geoms. But is it possible to create singlepart geoms from multipart geoms without making a new table (ST_DUMP)? And in the memory take every converted geom, and get its center point.
Is it possible?

Comment: `ST_Dump` doesn't create a new table, it returns a set of results. Look at the 1st example in the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) and apply the centroid function instead of ST_AsEWKT

Answer (score 4):

With a `LATERAL` table function expression (as implicit `CROSS JOIN`) instead of record notation selection (`(ST_Dump()).*`) - flexible, fast and elegant:

```
SELECT t.<id>,
       ST_Centroid(dmp.geom) AS geom    -- ST_PointOnSurface(dmp.geom)
FROM   <table> AS t,
       LATERAL ST_Dump(t.<geom>) AS dmp
;
```